# Pass variable back to originial view

Tags: android, android-intent, android-edittext

I set my `setContentView` then use intent to open a new `startActivity` ontop of the parent `view`. I have a string in the new `childView` and want to populate an `EditText` in the parent view, how would i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way would be to `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity` ([see example here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html). Alternatively you could use a visible object on your first `Activity` (with the `public` keyword, for instance) and use the `onResume` events, for instance, but I'd stick with the first method if I were you...

Comment: i went with `startActivityForResult` and `onActivityResult` found it after asking the question

Answer (score 1):

You could pass in intent parameters as you navigate to your parent view from the child view if that is what you are doing. You simply have to extract the parameters and use them in the parent view. You could also use startActivityForResult(). Depending upon when you want your parent view updated, you could override either onPause() or onResume()